# I can't install Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: system-installation, 20.04, freeze

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on an Acer Laptop with Intel Core i5-3210M  64-bit 2.50 GHz CPU, 8 GB RAM, and a GT 630M 2GB graphics processor. Where is the problem?
I couldn't fix the error.

[image]

Comment: What is the hardware?

Comment: Acer Laptop

Intel Core i5-3210M 250 GHz
8 GB Ram
64 Bit
GT 630M 2GB

Comment: You may also try other flavor like [Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/20.04/release/ubuntu-mate-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso). It installs normally on such low resources. Buying more RAM is highly recommended. Web browsing with 2 Gb is a pain.

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu 21.10?  What is the reason you are installing an older version?  It could be this bug is fixed in 21.10.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different USB stick and make sure you first click "Try Ubuntu Before Installing" then start installing process from the desktop. This might solve your issue.

Comment: I've tried it before but it didn't work